# Getting Geofence Unique id and adding entities to Geofence in android

Tags: android, android-geofence

I have created Geofence in android using "Google Api V2" using GoogleLocationService.GeofeningApi.
Since, For adding entities with any particular Geofence we must need to have the unique id of geofence created. But in android google api-V2 I am unable to get the "unique id" generated for my Geofence created, As per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/geofences
How to get the Geofence unique id and how to add entities with Geofence using google api V2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by

> I am unable to get the "unique id"

As developer you are responsible for providing that `"unique id"` so where's the problem? All you have to do is: each time you create a goefence increment some numeric variable, add it to [Geofence.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setRequestId%28java.lang.String%29) and store that number for next geofence.

Comment: Thanks! I am already setting the geofence request id and saving it in shared preference for further id generation purpose. I was just confused that is this request id what is needed when adding the entities with geofence.

Comment: Can I add the entities with Geofences using google play service library in android? If not, How to achieve this in andorid? Should I use the rest api of google-geofence?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: I mean, after creating geofence, Now, I need to add some entities (which will be tracked) to this geofence, so that, If these entities enter in this geofence area, A notification could be generated. Since, for adding entities to the geofence we need the particular geofence id so that, the entities could be added to this particular geofence only. Now, I want to know how to do in the google play service library in android?

Comment: I think I catch the drift: it's not so easy as geofences are tied to a particular smartphone - if you want other person (i.e. other smartphone) to be monitored by those geofences you have to register exactly the same geofences again on that person's smartphone.